# set key for 'comment-or-uncomment-region in python-mode

Tags: key-bindings, python

i want a shortcut for the nice little function `comment-or-uncomment-region`.
The thing is, it works fine for me in every mode using `M-x comment-or-uncomment-region`. And espacially it works differently (`#` for python and `//` for C++) so everything is fine here.
 But as i said i want a shortcut for this.
So i wrote the following in my `init.el` file:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-;") 'comment-or-uncomment-region)
```

This now works for all my .cpp files, where I'm in c++-mode, but in python-mode it says, this function is not on a key.
But i think its global-set, so what am I doing wrong? Or are some other functions able to unset the key (maybe in the initialization) ?

Comment: A minimal recipe to repro it, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file), would help answering.

Comment: `python-mode` is probably binding its own command to the key in its keymap. Try binding the key to `python-mode-map` in `python-mode-hook` or using something like `eval-after-load`.

Comment: Thank you! A hook has done it. But it somehow doesnt know the comment character anymore, but with
`(add-hook 'python-mode-hook (local-set-key (kbd "C-;") 'comment-or-uncomment-region))'  and 
'(add-hook 'python-mode-hook (setq comment-start "#"))`
it works. Im sure this isnt the cleanest way, but it works ! Thank you for that hint! @DoMiNeLa10

Comment: Curious why you don't just use `comment-dwim`? I think it is bound by default to `M-;`

Comment: @Reddy these won't work properly, as `add-hook` takes a function as the argument.

Comment: Don't know what ive done this morning, but youre right, it doesnt work anymore... @DoMiNeLa10.

Comment: And @WillyLee this is definitely an option.

Answer (score 1):

Major modes have their own keymaps, and `python-mode` probably overrides the binding from the global one. You can fix this by adding a hook that will set the key in `python-mode`'s map like this:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-;") #'comment-or-uncomment-region)))
```

Comment: That sounds good, but sadly doesn't work for me. I also tried to do it not via the init.el file, with 'M-x global-set-key RET C-;  comment-or-uncomment-region' (same with local while in python mode) and it still doesnt change it. So I think it is not overwritten.